# How do i show the current CodePush Version label in my React Native Android app?

Tags: react-native, code-push

Looking for something like:

`<Text>VERSION={CodePush.VersionLabel}</Text>`

Where CodePush.VersionLabel is something like "v6" that is displayed in `code-push deployment ls <MyApp>`

I'd like to show this at the bottom my login screen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
componentDidMount(){
    codePush.getUpdateMetadata().then((metadata) =>{
      this.setState({label: metadata.label, version: metadata.appVersion, description: metadata.description});
    });
}

render() {
    return(
        <Text>{this.state.version}.{this.state.label}</Text>
    );
}
```

Note: The `.label` property is the internal build number used by CodePush (e.g. `v24`)

Comment: `metadata` will be `null` if it is the codepush bundle packaged with the binary https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/api-js.md#codepushgetupdatemetadata

Comment: @julestruong because package info is readed from some kind of internal codepush file via async IO API

Answer (score 8):

If there are no updates available, getUpdateMetadata() returns null...

Workaround:

```
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";

async function getAppVersion() {
    const [{ appVersion }, update] = await Promise.all([
    codePush.getConfiguration(),
    codePush.getUpdateMetadata()
    ]);

    if (!update) {
        return `v${appVersion}`;
    }

    const label = update.label.substring(1);
    return `v${appVersion} rev.${label}`;
};

export { getAppVersion };
```

Example output: **v1.4.4"** OR **v1.4.4 rev.5"** depending on state.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to use it as a custom hook.

**1. Prepare the hook**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push'
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'

async function getOTAVersion() {
  try {
    const update = await codePush.getUpdateMetadata()

    return update ? update.label : null
  } catch (error) {
    return null
  }
}

export function useOTAVersion() {
  const [appVersion, setAppVersion] = useState(DeviceInfo.getReadableVersion())

  useEffect(() => {
    getOTAVersion().then((OTAVersion) => {
      if (OTAVersion) {
        setAppVersion(`${appVersion}/${OTAVersion}`)
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return { appVersion }
}
```

**2. Use the hook inside functional components**

```
import { useOTAVersion } from 'your/hooks'

const CmpExample = () => {
  const { appVersion } = useOTAVersion()

  return <Text>{appVersion}</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
componentDidMount() {
 CodePush.getCurrentPackage().then((update)=> {
    console.log('####### CodePush', update);
 });
}
```

Comment: `getCurrentPackage` is now [deprecated in favor of `getUpdateMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/react-native#api-reference)